# Python : Mask an image so that only pixels outside the mask

Tags: python, image, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am trying to mask an intensity image so that the areas outside of the mask become zero using python. I am doing this for a segmented image of multiple regions. I have a bounding box and binary image of the segment of interest (see code below)

Here is an extract of my code

`I2` = the intensity image

`Mask` = the binary mask

```
I2 = I.crop(RegionsBox[10]['BoundingBox'])
Mask = RegionsImage[10]['Image']
I2[Mask==0]=0
```

The last line returns an error....

I have implemented this successfully in matlab in the past with this line

```
I3 = I2.*uint8(Mask);
```

Does anyone know what the equivalent in Python might be?

Apologies if I have missed something obvious

Comment: Could you paste the error you receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your `I` and `I2` are Image objects and not just nd-arrays.
You can use numpy to convert `I2` into an array, apply the mask to it and then convert it back to an Image object:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
ndI2 = np.ararray( I2 )
ndI2 = ndI2 * Mask # apply the mask as you applied it in Matlab
I3 = Image.frombuffer( I2.mode, I2.size, ndI2, "raw", I2.mode, 0, 1 )
```